# percorrer uma lista ate chegar em determinada posição Golang

Tags: lista, golang, range

preciso percorrer uma lista que contem 11 itens mas quero parar no item 9. Esse é o meu codigo até o momento porem ele percorre toda a lista.

```
n = 10
for i := range lista{
        total += lista[i] * n
        n -= 1
    }
```

tentei fazer algo como mostrado abaixo, porem não deu certo!

```
n = 10
for i := range (len(lista) - 2){
        total += lista[i] * n
        n -= 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `range` deve ser usado num array ou slice. Diferente de outras linguages (como Python), o `range` não pode ser usado como valor númerico (como de 0...10).

Sua pergunta não define o que é uma "lista", já que slices e arrays são distintos. Irei assumir que seja um slice.

---

Você pode fazer isso de várias formas, ambas com o `for`:

```
for (i := 0; i < 9; i++) {
   total += lista[i] * n 
}
```

Você também pode criar um "novo slice" redimencionado:

```
for _, item := range lista[:len(lista)-2] {
   total += item* n 
}
```

Note que, neste caso estamos criando um novo slice usando `lista[:len(lista)-2]` ou pode usar `lista[:9]`. Quando eu digo "um novo slice", você não está copiando os dados, lembre-se que os slices possuem uma referencia interna, portanto está apenas criando novos 24 bytes, sendo eles: o ponteiro para o dado original, o tamanho (que definiu usando o `:len(lista)`) e a capacidade.

*Note que deve verificar o tamanho do slice antes de ambos os for, uma vez que pode causar um out-of-bound.*

---

Se quiser redimencioanr a capacidade, pode também usar `lista[:9:9]`, mas isso não é necessário. Caso queria "avançar", pode definir isso no inicio, como `lista[1:9]`, isso fará ignorar o primeiro item. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Definimos o limite de vezes que queremos passar no loop na variável `stopIndex`, comparamos o index atual com nossa variável e chegamos no momento de stop loop.
O comando break é acionado e seguimos o fluxo normal.
Existem diversas maneiras de fazer o caso solicitado, acredito que essa é uma forma simples e de rápido entendimento.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    list := []string{
        "Cereais", "Tangerina", "Castanha", "Banana", "Repolho",
        "Cogumelos", "Pepino", "Manga", "Nozes", "Batatas",
        "Alcachofra",
    }

    stopIndex := 9

    for index, item := range list {
        //Are we at index 9?
        if stopIndex == index {
            break
        }

        fmt.Println(item)
    }

}
```